# Xunit Prevent base class to execute tests

Tags: c#, xunit.net

I have recently started using XUnit, we have several methods that we need to test that all use the same test methods and same test data. Obviously creating a base class that contains all the test methods and call a virtual method that can be overriden was my first approach.
However when I execute the test runner, the base class is also executed and since the virtual method doesn't contain any code, most of these tests fail.

So how should I structure this code so that the methods in BaseEmployeeTest are not called?

```
public class BaseEmployeeTest : IEmployeeTest
{


    public virtual void CallTestMethod(string userSessionId, long employeeId)
    {
        // no-op 
    }

    [Theory]
    [MemberData(nameof(TestData.Emp), MemberType = typeof(Data))]
    public void Pu_CanSee_Own_Customer_Employees(long employeeId)
    {
        var ex = Record.Exception(() => CallTestMethod(_fixture.PuUserSessionId, employeeId));


        Assert.Null(ex);
    }
}

public class Test : BaseEmployeeTest
{
    public override void CallTestMethod(string userSessionId, long employeeId)
    {
        CallTestDataMethod("x", "y"
    }
}
```

Comment: try using interface instead of extending the base class

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you make it `abstract`, that should cover your need, i.e. replace

```
public class BaseEmployeeTest
```

with

```
public abstract class BaseEmployeeTest
```